# Primefaces <p:dataExporter> downloads with no format

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to use PrimeFaces  to export a dataTable to csv and xls but after the file has been downloaded, it has no file format.

After I click the export button and save the file to my disk, instead of being saved as **daily report.xls** it just saves it as **daily**.

The weird thing is this happens on firefox, when I use chrome it exports the file correctly with file format. I'm using **PrimeFaces 5.1**.

Below is my code for the export button

```
            <p:commandLink id="exportExcel" title="Export to Excel" ajax="false">
                <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="report" fileName="daily report" />
                <h:graphicImage library="img" name="icons/excel-file-icon.svg" styleClass="icon-medium" />
            </p:commandLink>
            <p:commandLink id="exportCsv" title="Export to CSV" ajax="false">
                <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="report" fileName="daily report" />
                <h:graphicImage library="img" name="icons/csv-file-icon.svg" styleClass="icon-medium" />
            </p:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space in fileName attribute of `<p:dataExporter>` e.g. instead of "Daily Report", provide "DailyReport". It should work just fine. May be a bug in Primefaces cross browser support for the component, but this workaround should land you a file with proper extension in Firefox.